# Left swipe (menu) - Google Maps

Tags: objective-c, swift, google-maps

Мне нужно открыть меню свайпом. Метод ниже не работает.

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMap: GMSMapView!

leftSwipe.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
leftSwipe.edges = .Left
googleMap.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
```

**P.S.** Delegate есть, методов в карте для свайпа я не нашёл.

```
googleMap.delegate = self
googleMap.myLocationEnabled = true
googleMap.sendSubviewToBack(globalMap)
googleMap.camera = camera
```

Comment: возможно на карте есть свой свайп рекогнайзер, который перехватывает тач и не дает вашему отработать

Comment: Попробуйте указать delegate = self и указать протокол

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мое решение

UIView ширеною 15px добавил в левую часть экрана.
Сделал UIView прозрачным и повесил на него addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

Так заработало, другого решения не нашел.